# Runtime C# knowing if 32-bit or 64-bit version of COM Interface is being used

Tags: c#, interop, x86, 64-bit, regsvr32

I want to build a DLL Class Library use COM Interop, with C#, target ANY CPU, and register it as 32-bit and 64-bit interfaces.

I want to be able to, at runtime, display what interface was used - if I am using the 32-bit version, or 64-bit version.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order for a process to load a 32-bit DLL, the process has to be 32-bit. And same for 64-bit. So to find out what has been loaded, assuming it has already worked, you just need to find out the bit-ness of the CLR:

```
if (System.IntPtr.Size == 8)
{
    // 64-bit
}
else
{
    // 32-bit
}
```

PS. for discussion of whether you need to check for a size of 16, see [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342433/what-is-going-to-happen-to-our-primative-types-when-128-bit-processors-come-out#342486).

Comment: You could just say if(IntPtr.Size==8)

Comment: You don't handle the other case, when it's not 8 and it's not 32-bit.

Comment: @Ian Boyd - Correct. But why would you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342433/what-is-going-to-happen-to-our-primitive-types-when-128-bit-processors-come-out/342486#342486

Answer (score 0):

and again, what about 32-bit processes running on win64 ?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3461562/1498669

If you're using .Net 4.0, it's a one-liner for the current process:

`Environment.Is64BitProcess`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitprocess.aspx