# How to determine whether a System.Diagnostics.Process is 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: .net, windows, process, 64-bit, system.diagnostics

I tried:

```
process.MainModule.FileName.Contains("x86")
```

But it threw an exception for a x64 process:

> Win32Exception: Only a part of the ReadProcessMemory ou WriteProcessMemory request finished

Comment: You are asking the wrong question.  Real question should be: "how did I screw up the ReadProcessMemory call?"

Comment: @Hans I don't care at all about this call as long as the question title is answered. The problem I listed is just a method of answering the title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know a process is 32-bit or 64-bit programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953377/how-to-know-a-process-is-32-bit-or-64-bit-programmatically)

Comment: @Jesse the question you pointed asks about the current process, not another process.

Comment: look at my answer.  It takes into account other processes as the OP wasn't clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to call [IsWow64Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139.aspx) via P/Invoke:

```
[DllImport( "kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi )]
[return: MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )]
public static extern bool IsWow64Process( [In] IntPtr processHandle, [Out, MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )] out bool wow64Process );
```

Here's a helper to make it a bit easier to call:

```
public static bool Is64BitProcess( this Process process )
{
    if ( !Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem )
        return false;

    bool isWow64Process;
    if ( !IsWow64Process( process.Handle, out isWow64Process ) )
        throw new Win32Exception( Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() );

    return !isWow64Process;
}
```

Comment: this method will fail in 32-bit Windows

Comment: On 32-bit Windows all processes are 32-bit, so there's no need to do check. I've edited Is64BitProcess to reflect this.

Comment: Use Process.SafeHandle property to prevent GC cleaning up process.Handle while WinAPI is called.

Answer (score 1):

Neither WMI's [`Win32_Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(VS.85).aspx) or [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) offer any explicit property.

How about iterating through the loaded modules ([`Process.Modules`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.modules.aspx)), a 32bit process will have loaded `%WinDir%\syswow64\kernel32.dll` while a 64bit process will have loaded it from `%WinDir%\system32\kernel32.dll` (this is the one dll that *every* Windows process loads).

NB. This test will, of course, fail on a x86 OS instance.

Comment: also fails if running in 32-bit proces while accessing modules of 64-bit process with Win32Exception "A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process."

Answer (score 1):

`Environment.Is64BitProcess` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: That only tells you if the calling process is 64-bit, I think the OP wants to know if another process is 64-bit

Comment: @Phil: Yeah, I wasn't sure what the OP's intent was. I figure he can downvote or comment.