# Using WMI, how can I determine whether a remote process is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: c#, 64-bit, wmi, win32-process

I have a collection of win32_process objects queried from a remote machine using WMI. How do I determine whether each process is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Related: [How to determine whether a System.Diagnostics.Process is 32 or 64 bit?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3575785/113116)

Answer (score 1):

WMI doesn't have this functionality. The solution is to test each process's `Handle` using [`IsWow64Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139.aspx) via P/Invoke. [This code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575785/how-to-determine-whether-a-system-diagnostics-process-is-32-or-64-bit/3576797#3576797t) should help you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a go.Quite strange that they don't have a way of identifying that in the process class, or even in the .NET API for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieves the platform information from the process architecture.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="path"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string GetPlatform(string path)
{
    string result = "";
    try
    {
        const int pePointerOffset = 60;
        const int machineOffset = 4;
        var data = new byte[4096];
        using (Stream s = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            s.Read(data, 0, 4096);
        }
        // Dos header is 64 bytes, last element, long (4 bytes) is the address of 
        // the PE header
        int peHeaderAddr = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, pePointerOffset);
        int machineUint = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, peHeaderAddr +
                                                      machineOffset);
        result = ((MachineType) machineUint).ToString();
    }
    catch { }

    return result;
}



public enum MachineType
{
    Native = 0,
    X86 = 0x014c,
    Amd64 = 0x0200,
    X64 = 0x8664
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this process is accurate but tends to be a bit heavy with enough processes in queue. I call this per process in another thread to alleviate the UI.

Comment: You are writing this code in C#.  A language whose EXEs can run either in 32-bit or 64-bit mode.  You can't tell from the EXE header.

Comment: You can compile to a specific platform. Otherwise, why have 2 different releases of the same executable?

Comment: Why have two when you can have *one* that works on both platforms?  AnyCPU is cool.