# How load the Dll according to platform

Tags: vb.net, visual-c++, dll, dllnotfoundexception

I have a dll for 32bit and 64bit and now I want that my exe call the dll from according to solution platform,means when x64 is set then the dll of 64bit will call.For this I declare a function GetPlatform().

```
Public Function GetPlateform() As String

    Dim var1 As String
    If (IntPtr.Size = 8) Then
        var1 = hellox64
    Else
        var1 = hello
    End If
    Return var1
End Function
```

and when the form load
this var1 is assign to var and finally.

```
Public Declare Function function1 Lib "var" (ByVal Id As Integer) As Integer
```

But When I debug the code "DllNotFoundException" is ocuured.
**NOTE:**The dll is in vc++.

Comment: Install the correct DLL with only one name!!!! create 2 setup packages

Comment: But @Martin Is this possible or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store your native dlls into subfolders and hint the [Library Loader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586) by filling accordingly the `PATH` process environment variable with the path to the correct version to load.

For instance, given this tree layout...

> ```
> Your_assembly.dll
>   |_NativeBinaries
>       |_x86
>           |_your_native.dll
>       |_amd64
>           |_your_native.dll
> ```

...and this code (sorry, C#, no VB.Net :-/ )...

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    private const string nativeName = "your_native";

    static NativeMethods()
    {
        string originalAssemblypath = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath;

        string currentArchSubPath = "NativeBinaries/x86";

        // Is this a 64 bits process?
        if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
        {
            currentArchSubPath = "NativeBinaries/amd64";
        }

        string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(originalAssemblypath), currentArchSubPath);

        const string pathEnvVariable = "PATH";
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(pathEnvVariable,
            String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", path, Path.PathSeparator, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(pathEnvVariable)));
    }

    [DllImport(nativeName)]
    public static extern int function1(int param);

    [DllImport(nativeName)]
    public static extern int function2(int param);
}
```

...`function1` and `function2` would be dynamically bound to either the 32 or 64 bits version of the native code, depending on the size of an IntPtr (more on this in this post from **[Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasics32bitAnd64bitConfusionAroundX86AndX64AndTheNETFrameworkAndCLR.aspx)** or this **[StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953377/how-to-know-a-process-is-32-bit-or-64-bit-programmatically)**).

**Note 1:** This solution is especially useful when both versions of the dll bear the same name or if you're not willing to duplicate every extern references.

**Note 2:** This has already been successfully implemented in **[LibGit2Sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/Core/NativeMethods.cs)**.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot dynamically create a reference to the DLL in a lib statement. However, you may (disclaimer: have not tried) be able to create two references and call the appropriate one in your code.

```
Public Declare Function Function132 Lib "My32BitLib.DLL" Alias "function1" (ByVal Id As Integer) As Integer

Public Declare Function Function164 Lib "My64BitLib.DLL" Alias "function1" (ByVal Id As Integer) As Integer
```

You will then need to branch on the platform and call the appropriate alias function name (Function132 or Function164) depending on the platform.

Comment: Swap your function names and the Aliases. You want `Declare Function function164 ... Alias "Function1"`