# Find out process bitness programmatically

Tags: .net

Is there anyway I can find out if my .NET process is running as 32bit process or 64bit process?

Comment: Ok, 2565 more points to go, before I can mark that as a duplicate!

Answer (score 5):

You probably want [Environment.Is64BitProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitprocess.aspx) if you're using .NET 4.0 or later. Otherwise, check `IntPtr.Size`, as suggested in the other answers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to new API, this should be a preferable way

Comment: +1 Indeed a much better way than using IntPtr

Comment: +1 - This looks better. Nice!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
    // 32-bit

else if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
    // 64-bit
```

[From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953377/how-to-know-a-process-is-32-bit-or-64-bit-programmatically)

However, as pointed by @Jim Mischel, on .NET 4 and above, you should use

[`Environment.Is64BitProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitprocess.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use IntPtr.Size property to find out process bitness.

```
if(IntPtr.Size == 4)
 // 32 bit process
else
 // 64bit process
```