# C# and PInvoke into 32/64 bit DLL

Tags: c#, nuget, pinvoke

I am creating a class library, which I hope to put on NuGet eventually. Right now, it is targeting AnyCPU.

I now want to PInvoke into a DLL, which comes in both 32 and 64 bit versions. Initially, I thought I'd just use the 32 bit version, but this threw a BadImageFormatException. I changed the library to target X86 only, and while this works, it requires the caller to be a 32 bit process too. This naturally wouldn't work for a NuGet project.

Appreciate any thoughts on how to work with the 32/64 bit versions of the native library, and how to package this up in NuGet (prefer not to have 2 different assemblies).

Comment: Take a look at how SQLite does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check platform at runtime and PInvoke into different DLLs.

```
static void NativeFuncWrapper(){
    if(Environment.Is64BitProcess){
        NativeFuncWrapper64(); //this calls 64-bit dll
    }else{
        NativeFuncWrapper32(); //this calls 32-bit dll
    }
}
```

If you want it to work without `Environment.Is64BitProcess`, read [How to know a process is 32-bit or 64-bit programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953377/how-to-know-a-process-is-32-bit-or-64-bit-programmatically) for alternative methods.