# How to detect bitness of a process by its ID?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How can I detect if a process is running in x86 or x64 mode given an ID of this process?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1953411/894111

Comment: @Omidam81, that question is about checking bitness of the _current_ process. I need to check _another_ process.

Comment: yes and it exactly answer your question. just check second part of its answer.

Comment: @seticer: no, that question was about checking the bitness of another process, it's just that some of the answers misinterpreted it.  An exact duplicate.

Comment: @Harry Johnston, I wonder why plainly irrelevant answers aren't deleted.