# How do I check if the DLL file is suitable for 32 bit or 64 bit version?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dll, 32bit-64bit

There are 64 bit and 32 bit version for DLL file.
For example in mscvcr.dll there are 2 version 32 bit and 64 bit.
how can i check if the DLL is running for 64 bit or 32 bit Windows Version with VB.net?

Comment: If your exe targets 64-bit, then it will use the 64-bit version of the DLL.  Likewise for 32-bit.

Comment: Are you referring to the DLL as loaded into the current process, or another process?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270531/how-to-determine-if-a-net-assembly-was-built-for-x86-or-x64

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3461562/89586

Comment: Referring for another process.

Comment: Simplest way is to just try it.  Next way is to use Dumpbin.exe /headers on the file and look at the reported machine type.