# c# Windows 10 virtual keyboard issues

Tags: c#, windows-10, virtual-keyboard

I have developed a c# code snippet to determine if the virtual (on-screen) keyboard was showing or not.

The code below worked fine in Windows 7, 8 and 8.1, but in Windows 10, the `IsKeyboardVisible` always returns `true`...

```
public static bool IsKeyboardVisible() {
    Process keyboardProc;
    UInt32 WS_DISABLED = 0x8000000;
    UInt32 WS_VISIBLE = 0X94000000;
    int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    IntPtr keyboardHandle = GetKeyboardWindowHandle();

    bool visible = false;

    if (keyboardHandle != IntPtr.Zero) {
        UInt32 style = GetWindowLong(keyboardHandle, GWL_STYLE);
        // in Win10, this always returns "true", i.e. WS_DISABLED is
        // 
        //visible = ((style & WS_DISABLED) != WS_DISABLED);
        // UPDATE: I found this code helping here
        visible = (style == WS_VISIBLE);
    }
    return visible;
}
```

I used a tutorial on SO, but it's a while ago so sorry for not crediting the author.

Does anyone know about a working code snippet for all recent Windows versions, so I don't have to check the actual OS to switch on the version...?

**UPDATE**

I found the [original post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774139/show-touch-keyboard-tabtip-exe-in-windows-10-anniversary-edition), which allowed me to correct the code. So now my problem is the same old Win10 issue - I can't show the virtual keyboard using

```
string progFiles = @"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink";
string keyboardPath = Path.Combine(progFiles, "TabTip.exe");
keyboardProc = Process.Start(keyboardPath);
```

... Again, is there any "all-platform" code I can use, or what is the suggested approach for Win10?

**UPDATE 2**
I found out about issues running a 32-bit application on a 64-bit os. That being said, the error occurs whether I try to run `osk.exe` in the `System32` or the "sysWOW64` folder... Is there any other way than making a 64-bit release???

Answer (score 1):

After much digging about `TabTip.exe`, `osk.exe` and x86 and x64 compatibility issues, I found a solution by searching the `osk.exe` on my system and trying to run each of them. I found 4 version the following folders:

- `C:\Windows\System32`
- `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`
- `C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft...`
- `C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft...`

It appears the one in `C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft...` works fine (not the other three though)...

Given the "amd64_...." folder might not be the same on different machines (I actually checked and they don't match, I didn't search whether this depends on the machine, the windows build or anything else...).

So basically I did a small routine to look into `WinSxS` folder and returning the very firs occurrence of `osk.exe`, which works just fine. I also made the code working on a 32-bit OS using a simple OS-architecture test:

```
 string OSKpath64 = getOskPath(@"C:\Windows\WinSxS");
 if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(OSKpath64)) {
     OSKpath64 = "osk.exe";
  }
  string OSKpath32 = @"C:\Windows\System32\osk.exe";
  if (!File.Exists(OSKpath32)) {
      OSKpath32 = @"osk.exe";
  }
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start((Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem) ? OSKpath64 : OSKpath32);
```

**UPDATE:** 
The confusion with one working and one non-working version within the `WinSxS` folder made me nervous. It works just fine because the `amd_..` folder is alphabetically before `wow64_...`.

I therefore suggest to add a test in the `getOskPath` method to return the first native 64-bit `osk.exe` (not the emulated one).

Using the `IsWin64Emulator` [method found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1953411/2490877), the method looks like this:

```
static string getOskPath(string dir) {
    string path = Path.Combine(dir, "osk.exe");
    if (File.Exists(path)) {
        Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
        if (p.IsWin64Emulator()) {
            path = string.Empty;
        }
        p.Kill();
        return path;
    }
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
    foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in di.GetDirectories().Reverse()) {
        path = getOskPath(Path.Combine(dir, subDir.Name));
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)) {
            return path;
        }
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with me, I try all answer here, but it not work. 
After finding solution with google, this is is ok.

```
// Step 1: For Load On-Screen Keyboard
    const string Kernel32dll = "Kernel32.Dll";
    [DllImport(Kernel32dll, EntryPoint = "Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection")]
    public static extern bool Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref IntPtr ptr);

    [DllImport(Kernel32dll, EntryPoint = "Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection")]
    public static extern bool Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection(IntPtr ptr);

    IntPtr wow64Value;
    //---------------------------------------

   // Step 2: Function-----
   if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
            {
                if (Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref wow64Value))
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");
                    Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection(wow64Value);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");
            }
   //----------------
```

Comment: That is risky, it affects the CLR and just-in-time compiler as well.  Simplest way is to execute c:\windows\sysnative\osk.exe, "sysnative" tells the file system director that you meant to use the native one and never want it redirected.

Comment: This code I just follow the example in and it work for me. So I just share (because I also got the difficult to file solution). Actually I don't clearly understand this code, so if you have better way, can you share it?